# Mysql decimal type performance by digits setting

Tags: mysql, decimal

I read online doc about Mysql decimal type size:

| Leftover Digits | Number of Bytes |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1–2 | 1 |
| 3–4 | 2 |
| 5–6 | 3 |
| 7–9 | 4 |

So we know that digits number 7~9 occupied same size in disk, but how about performance? Is 7 digits same as 9 digits or better?

Comment: Why do you believe that the number of digits affect performance at all?

Comment: I thought less digits means less 0&1, means better performance

Comment: Just because storage space is optimized to conserve space, doesn't mean that in-memory handling can be optimized. You're running on a 64-bit CPU, so calculations are done in 64-bit there, then truncated again when stored back in the database.

Comment: @Andreas - The 3 numeric types are handled by different hardware/software: `DECIMAL`, `BIGINT` (and `INT`, etc), `DOUBLE` (and `FLOAT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DECIMAL` is implemented by a library that assumes that 2 digits are packed per byte or 9 digits per 32-bit integer.  7 digits won't fit in 3 bytes; 9 will fit in 4 bytes.  The library allows up to 64 (or maybe only 63) digits -- a quite huge value.

In `DECIMAL(M,N)`, the data is limited based on M and N.  Whether it is limited to 7 or 9 should make no difference in performance.  Even if it does, the effort is very small compared to bigger issues, such as fetching the row.

Tip:  A simple Rule of Thumb:  `DECIMAL(M,N)` takes *about* M/2 bytes.

`DECIMAL(11,2)` for money allows up to a billion dollars/Euros/etc in 5 bytes.  I see no advantage in using (10,2) or (9,2), each of which is also 5 bytes.

Comment: Wouldn't (9,2) be 4 bytes?

Comment: @Andreas - there are 2 _separate_ parts, 7 digits before the decimal and 2 after.  The total size is the sum of the two sizes, hence 4+1 = 5.